# Double Fault в режиме ядра

Tags: c, windows, kernel, драйвер

Ставлю эксперименты надо Windows и столкнулся с такой проблемой: в режиме ядра выполняю следующий код

`mov  esp, 0XXXXXXXXh 
 ret`

И на команде `mov` система падает с ошибкой `UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP` с параметром `0x8`, что означает `Double Fault`. В MSDN написано, что чаще всего это либо переполнение стека ядра, либо ошибка оборудования. Понятно, что второе исключается.

Не могу понять, почему ошибка возникает сразу на этом месте. Понимаю, если бы это произошло на командах `push`, `pop` и т.п. Надеюсь, что кто-нибудь подскажет мне, в чем причина и что делать. Спасибо.

Comment: А что, по-вашему, делает `ret`?

Comment: выполняет переход по адресу, который лежит на вершине стека. (Если честно, этого я и хочу). Но до команды `ret` выполнение не доходит

Comment: А как вы определили, что не доходит? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov перед `mov` у меня `int3`, соответственно в WinDbg пошагово выполняю.

Comment: Так это перед mov, а как вы понимаете что сейчас mov, а не уже ret ?

Comment: @Mike А как можно по-другому в отладчике при пошаговом выполнении понять? По нажатию на F10 выполняется очередная команда. Либо я не понял Вашего вопроса.

Comment: Ага, отладчик что бы одну команду выполнить и остановиться ставит после нее свой int3. И вот в момент его вызова то и происходит беда со стеком

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый шаг отладчика - это `int 1`. А инструкции int нужен стек.

Comment: Сейчас же попробую.

Comment: Да, действительно, это я по глупости не учел. Спасибо, буду знать